# How to change plot title in R when the package already uses an existing title?

Tags: r, graph

I am using an R package called mixer. I want to produce some plots using the package but with my own plot title. However the plots already have existing titles. I tried to set main = NULL and use the title command to reproduce the title. But it doesn't work.... below is an example:

```
 require("mixer")
 data(macaque)
 mixer(macaque,qmin=8)->xout
 plot(xout, frame = 3, main = "")
 title("Something else")
```

If you can let me know a general solution for changing plot title when a package already has an existing plot title, that would be great! Thank you!

Comment: This code calls `mixer:::plotmixture` which unfortunately is hardcoded with a title.

Comment: Does that mean there's no way to change the titles....? :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a really cheap trick.

```
require(mixer)
data(macaque)
mixer(macaque,qmin=8)->xout
par(col.main='white') # Switch the plot title colour to white.
plot(xout, frame = 3, main = "")
par(col.main='black') # Switch back to black.
title("Some title")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried several hacks including `col,main` inside of plot.  Didn't think to do it to `par` +1 hack.  The package author should be informed of this problem so that maybe a title isn't required to be plotted or additional arguments can control the title.

Comment: `par(col.main="#00000000")` or anything with `00` as the last two digits in the hex code is an alternative that will make the text transparent and essentially disappear it from appearing or being selectable in a pdf document.